# How to simply create a custom view without duplicate LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

The simplest way I found to create a custom view, so I don't have to handle annoying things like to override the onLayout() method, is to make it inherit from a LinearLayout. I also have a LinearLayout at the root of the associated XML file that I inflate, so there is 2 of them at the root.

How can I optimise this, by removing one of this extra LinearLayout, but keep it simple to create custom views ?

**MyToolbar.kt:**

```
class MyToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) :
    LinearLayoutCompat(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val binding = MyToolbarBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

    init {
         // [...] Initialization of my view ...
    }
}
```

**my_toolbar.xml:**

```xml
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Actual content of my view -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `<merge>` tag inside `my_toolbar.xml` instead of `<LinearLayout>`.

Answer (score 0):

As Pawel suggested you could use [merge](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge) to do that.

This is a sample from the developer website:

```xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Here you can add your custom content views.. -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete"/>

</merge>
```

Comment: @Pawel You totally skipped the attributes of the `LinearLayout` (width, height, gravity and orientation). I tried to add them programmatically in the `init` function before inflating the subview and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What I have right now after @Pawel and @Cata suggestion. This doesn't work, the `LinearLayout` use the whole height of the parent, but it should only wrap its content.

**MyToolbar.kt:**

```
class MyToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) :
    LinearLayoutCompat(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val binding

    init {
        // Tried to add the attributes here as they seems ignored on the `merge` tag
        gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
        orientation = HORIZONTAL
        layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        binding = MyToolbarBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)

        // [...] Initialization of the view ...
    }
}
```

**my_toolbar.xml:**

```xml
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Actual content of the view -->

</merge>
```